# Angular 8 with Storybook 6

Tags: angular, angular8, storybook, angular-storybook

Getting the below error while installing and starting a storybook.

```
ERROR in /Users/username/angular-storybook/src/stories/Button.stories.ts
ERROR in /Users/username/angular-storybook/src/stories/Button.stories.ts(2,29):
TS2307: Cannot find module '@storybook/angular/types-6-0'.
```

ng version

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Node: 12.16.2
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
```

Dev dependency

```
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.0.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.0.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.12",
    "@storybook/angular": "^6.0.12"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a workaround, I have updated the imports from Button, Header, Page{.stories}:

```
From --->
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/angular/types-6-0';

To  ---->
import { Story, Meta } from '@storybook/angular';
```

This works fine. But not sure why the boilerplate code has the issue. :(
This works fine with version 6.0.12.

Updates:
With newer version of the storybook(>6.2.*),
Explicitly declare in typings.d.ts inside the .storybook directory. (mentioned by @Mr.7)

```
declare module '@storybook/angular'
```

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me some headache and I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I tried Subhakant's workaround but that didn't work for me. After some research I found this.

The explicit declaration in **typings.d.ts** inside **.storybook** directory made it work

`declare module '@storybook/angular'`

Answer (score 0):

For me none of this worked. I used `npx sb init` to add storybook to an existing Angular 6 project. Sadly it did not set up storybook correctly and I received the same error as OP, yet none of the solutions here worked for me. Finally I realized, that my typescript version was outdated (3.8.4) but the setup was for TS 3.9. I updated typescript to 3.10.4 everything works now.